# UICollectionView: Custom UI for a manually selected Cell

Tags: cell, uicollectionview, appearance, uicollectionviewcell

I'm overriding (BOOL)isSelected {} from UICollectionViewCell to change the cells appearance on selection. This does work as intend if I'm clicking on a cell. But the isSelected method never gets called if I'm setting the selection manually. Is there an elegant way to resolve this?

Overriden method in my custom cell:

```
 (BOOL)isSelected {
    if ([super isSelected]) {
        self.contentView.alpha = 0.2;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        return YES;
    } else {
        self.contentView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I want to manually select an cell in my controller like this:

```
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was to override the method isSelected.
I need to override the setter method setSelected everything works as expected.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
[super setSelected:selected];
if (selected) {
    self.contentView.alpha = 0.2;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
} else {
    self.contentView.alpha = 1.0;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

}